# Gulpfile not working when module.exports references a Gulp task not a function?

Tags: gulp

I have a sprite task in a gulp file:

```
var sprite = function() {
  // Do something
};

module.exports = {
  sprite: sprite
};
```

This was working but I now need to a run annother task prior to the sprite task. I need this prior task to complete before the sprite task runs, so Im using runSequence:

```
var spriteFirst = function() {
  // Do something first
};

var spriteSecond = function() {
  // Do something second 
};

gulp.task('sprite', function(callback) {
  runSequence('spriteFirst', 'spriteSecond',
    callback);
});

module.exports = {
  sprite: sprite
};
```

This code gives me the following error:

```
ReferenceError: sprite is not defined
```

It seems that the module.exports recognises 'sprite' if its a normal function, but not if its a Gulp task. Is this correct? If so why is this the case?

Comment: use gulp4, you can use native functions, and you dont even need runSequence

Answer (score 1):

Gulp tasks are **not** ordinary JavaScript functions. Each gulp task is an object that consists of a *name*, a *function* and (optionally) *the names of other tasks* it depends on. All of that information is stored in the `gulp` instance.

When you reference `sprite` in your source code, Node.js tries to find a `var` or `function` by that name. However there isn't one, since `gulp.task()` does not create a `var` or `function`. It merely stores the passed *name* and *function* as a new task object in the `gulp` instance.

Likewise you cannot run a task named `spriteFirst` using `runSequence()` without defining that task using `gulp.task()`. What will happen is that `runSequence()` will look in the `gulp` instance for a task object with the name  `spriteFirst`. However there isn't one, because you only declared a function named `spriteFirst`. You need to create a task object using `gulp.task()`.

That means your code should look like this:

```
var spriteFirst = function() {
  // Do something first
};

var spriteSecond = function() {
  // Do something second 
};

var sprite = function(callback) {
  runSequence('spriteFirst', 'spriteSecond',
    callback);
};

gulp.task('spriteFirst', spriteFirst);
gulp.task('spriteSecond', spriteSecond);
gulp.task('sprite', sprite);

module.exports = {
  sprite: sprite
};
```